# How to display two decimal places when we type a value in a textbox?

Tags: c#, textbox

I would like to know how to display two decimal places when we type a value(money) in a text box.

```
private void txtAmountRecieved_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtAmountRecieved.Text = Convert.ToDouble(txtAmountRecieved.Text)
        .ToString("#,0.00");           
}
```

I tried above code. But when I type 1 value in textbox, cursor became in-front of value 1. So I cant type continuously in this textbox without interupt. And also an error occurred when I insert this value to database, which is

> Input string was not in a correct format.

So how to solve this?

Comment: You sure the value of `txtAmountRecieved.Text` can be converted to a `decimal`?

Comment: sorry it should be convert.to double

Comment: Do you want it to format as they type or when they tab to another control? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215989/textbox-for-price-cash-currency-on-c-sharp

Comment: You might be better off using a `NumericUpDownControl`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textbox for price/cash/currency on C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215989/textbox-for-price-cash-currency-on-c-sharp)

Comment: What you're doing is going to be difficult in the textchanged event. I mean you could add the line `txtAmountReceived.SelectionStart = txtAmountReceived.Text.IndexOf(".");` but that has its drawbacks too. Anytime you try to manipulate a format on the textchanged you will find yourself fighting the cursor. Plus to elaborate on maccettura's comment, what if the user types something that cannot be converted to a numeric value

Comment: thank you gunnerone. Found the exact answer

Answer (score 3):

You can try this. Also you can specify the count after decimal you want

decimal amount= Math.Round(convert.todecimal(textbox.text)), 2);